# WELD-001437: Normal scoped bean class javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot is not proxyable because the type is final or it contains a final method

Tags: jsf, glassfish, cdi, weld

When deploying a dynamic web project with JSF facet to Eclipse+GlassFish, the following error occurs:

[image: error screenshot]

The message says:

> WELD-001437: Normal scoped bean class javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot is not proxyable because the type is final or it contains a final method public final void javax.faces.component.UIComponent.popComponentFromEL(javax.faces.context.FacesContext) - com.sun.faces.cdi.ViewProducer@1ccfebd3

How is this caused and how can I solve it? The same codebase and server works fine in Netbeans.

Comment: Note : I dont use CDI

Comment: So, you don't have a `beans.xml` in project? Also not in WAR?

Answer (score 0):

Because your NetBeans project has been worked successful. In this case, You should **import exist NetBeans project to Eclipse IDE**, don't create new Eclipse project. This make avoid errors or mistakes.

Turn off all other web application servers, avoid port number collision.